# Stripe integration issue : Your card's security code is invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I want to implement stripe in my application. I am using Credit Card Number: 4242 4242 4242 4242 Exp month :02 Exp Year:20 for testing purpose.Previously it was working fine But suddenly it started giving me error "Your card's security code is invalid"

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it happens when the CVC starts with 0. Always convert the integer to String before passing to stripe API.

Answer (score 0):

You must enter info like below, `Cvc` must be 3 digit like `777`.

```
 var MyToken = new StripeTokenCreateOptions();
 MyToken.Card = new StripeCreditCardOptions
 {
      AddressCountry = "USA",
      AddressLine1 = "TEST",
      AddressLine2 = "TEST",
      AddressCity = "Chicago",
      AddressZip = "12345",
      Cvc = "777",
      ExpirationMonth = 10,
      ExpirationYear = 20,
      Name = "Blue naina",
      Number = "5555555555554444"
 };
```